# if --- else javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What I want is to call function b with parameter arr1, if arr1 has at least one value in it, else if arr1 is empty call function b with parameter arr2. However the else block is not calling function b when arr1 is empty.

```
function a(){
    let arr1 = [];
    let arr2 = [];
    if(arr1){
        b(arr1);
    }
    else {
        b(arr2);
    }   
}

function b(arr){
    doSomething with arr;
}
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't consider an array to be falsey when it is empty. Use arr1.length for truthy / falsey values.

Comment: Thank you Charles. That was on spot. Now fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

an empty array [] is not a falsy value in javascript, you need to check by the length

```js
function a(){
    let arr1 = [];
    let arr2 = [];
    if(arr1.length > 0){
        b(arr1);
    }
    else {
        b(arr2);
    }   
}

function b(arr){
    console.log('iside b')
}

a()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is you're checking if arr1 is undefined. Which will return true because arr1 is not undefined because it's an empty array.

You should check for its length:

```
if (arr1.length > 0) {
 b(arr1);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @AbrahamG. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){
    let arr1 = [];
    let arr2 = [];
    arr1.length ? b(arr1) : b(arr2)
}

function b(arr){
    console.log('iside b')
}

a()
```